# Why This macros is not expanding correctly?

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize the array as follows :

```
   static tha_field_info_t person_t_fields[] = {
            HA_FIELD_INFO(person_t, name, CHAR)
    };
```

Relevant Data structures:

```
typedef struct _tha_field_info_{
    char fname[128];
    DATA_TYPE_t dtype;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int offset;
} tha_field_info_t;

typedef struct _person{
    char name[30];
    unsigned int age;
} person_t;
```

Macros used

```
#define HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, name)       ((int)&((st *)0)->name)
#define HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, name)         sizeof (((st *)0)->name)

#define HA_FIELD_INFO (st, fname, dtype)   \
{#fname, dtype, HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, fname), HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, fname)}
```

Seeing Compilation errors with this macros.

```
tha.h:35:28: error: ‘fname’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tha.h:35:35: error: ‘dtype’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tha.h:36:2: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘{’ token
{#fname, dtype, HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, fname), HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, fname)}
tha.h:36:3: error: stray ‘#’ in program
{#fname, dtype, HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, fname), HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, fname)}
```

However, If i Hardcode like this, then its work fine.

`{"name", CHAR, sizeof(((person_t *)0)->name), ((int)&((person_t *)0)->name)}`

Basically, i want to store the array with field information of structure person_t.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Oh, wow, well spotted. I'd like to upvote this; please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Are you pointing to the space after closing bracket i macro definition. Well, i tried removing the space, but same error. Also, i have written many macros and i give lots of space before continuation character "\". Pls clarify.

Comment: Ok, got it  ... you have eagle eyes. :o Thanks.

Comment: How can i mark comment as an answer ?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of definition directives in C:

```
#define OBJECT_LIKE_MACRO     followed by a "replacement list" of preprocessor tokens
#define FUNCTION_LIKE_MACRO(with, arguments) followed by a replacement list
```

What distinguishes these two types of macros is the token that follows the identifier after `#define`: if it's an *lparen*, it is a function-like macro, and otherwise it's an object-like macro. What's an *lparen*? [Draft N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) points out in appendix A section 3:

> (6.10) lparen:
>     a **`(`** character not immediately preceded by white-space

As far as I know, this is one of the few cases in C where spacing matters (aside from `//` comments, line splicing, and preprocessing directives). And it kind of makes sense. After all, how would the preprocessor distinguish between any function-like macro and an object-like macro that has a replacement list starting with a `(` token? For instance, the following is an object-like macro, rather than a function-like macro with bad syntax:

```
#define NULL (void*)0
```

---

Let's now answer your question. The problem is in these two lines:

```
#define HA_FIELD_INFO (st, fname, dtype)   \
{#fname, dtype, HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, fname), HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, fname)}
```

Because the `(` character after `HA_FIELD_INFO` is "preceded by white-space", this is not the function-like macro that you intended it to be. Just remove that space:

```
#define HA_FIELD_INFO(st, fname, dtype)   \
{#fname, dtype, HA_FIELD_SIZE(st, fname), HA_FIELD_OFFSET(st, fname)}
```

Comment: Other examples where spacing matters: `- -i`, `i+ ++j`, `0x2E +1`. The latter is unexpected and a very difficult test for even advanced C programmers.

Comment: @chqrlie Fair point, but I was mostly referring to significant spacing being significant *after* tokenisation. I agree that `0x2E +1`/`0x2E+1` exposes a very nasty defect in the C11 specification.

Comment: The *defect* has been around since the first version of the standard.  I like this one too:  `check_pattern(date, "??/??/????");`